# How to get a required parameter from JSON response RobotFramework

Tags: python, api, automation, robotframework, robotframework-ide

As part of verification in Robot Framework, I have following data (stored as ${response}) as get request response:

```
        {
            "interfaces": [
                {
                    "name": "eth0",
                    "status": "ready",
                    "macAddress": "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx",
                    "ipv4": {
                        "mode": "DHCP",
                        "address": "127.0.0.1",
                        "mask": "255.255.255.0",
                    },
                    "ipv6": {
                        "mode": "DISABLED",
                        "addresses": [],
                        "gateway": "",
                    }
                }
            ],
            "result": 0
        }


        And I would like to get value of key ipv4 and store in variable 
        3 library is requestlibrary collection httplibrary.http
        is there anykeyword to save this value ? please help me
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Hey please have a look at the [How to Ask a good Question - Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And consider to NOT remove already approved edits. And please include more details: what have you tried, where to you fail...

Answer (score 1):

You can get and store the Value with the given code:

```
def get_activation_code():
    print(dict["data"]["user"]["activationCode"])
    return dict["data"]["user"]["activationCode"]
```

If you provide more information about the "sending to another API" task I could help you there too, but this method will provide the `activationCode`. `dict` refers to the given dictionary you get as a response as you say.

When you already get a response from somewhere I guess you already imported the `requests`- library?

A way so send something to another API would be trough the `post`-command:

```
r = requests.post(url = the_url_of_the_target_api, data = get_activation_code())
```

You then can catch the response with:

```
response = r.text
print(response)
```

Comment: Hope you Can See Uploaded Picture And Help Me

Answer (score 1):

The response you got is a string, convert it to a dict with the python's standard `json` library:

```
${as dict}=    Evaluate    json.loads("""${response}""")    json
```

And now you can work with it as a normal dictionary in Robot Framework:

```
${ipv4}=     Set Variable    ${as dict['interfaces'][0]['ipv4']}
```

Comment: ${as dict['interfaces'][0]['ipv4']} what is as dict

and another question is how store mode in ipv6 in variable

Comment: "dict" is short for a "dictionary", a variable type storing key:value pair; `${as dict}` is such variable that now holds the ipv4 object in the response. In what I have written, you can get the "mode" with `${as dict['mode']}`; you can also store it in another with `${mode}=   Set Variable    ${as dict['mode']}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the request library to access that:

```py
Create Session  server  http://mywebsite.com #You the ROOT URL here 
${response}=  Get Request  server  #You put the URI here
${var_dict}=    Evaluate     json.loads("""${response.content}""")    json
${ipv4}=    Set Variable    ${var_dict}[interfaces][ipv4]
```

This will store all the keys from ipv4 in the variable `${ipv4}`

Comment: Can you elaborate, where exactly is the "request" library used in your answer? Plus, that is not its name; nor is this answer anything but a copy of the already given.

Comment: @TodorMinakov He did all the steps to get a json with the requestslibrary. He can now store the content from the json in a variable

Comment: No, OP has not said that; and no, you are not using request library, with its incorrect name, in your answer. And yes, your answer is still just a copy of the other, not giving anything new.

Comment: @TodorMinakov I changed my answer. This should probably give an answer to his question